# Using CanCan authorize_resource in odd controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

Let's say I've controller:

```
class ExerciseImagesController < ApplicationController
  # authorize_resource class: Exercise::Image ?

  def create
    @image = Exercise::Image.create(image_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @exercise_image = Exercise::Image.find(params[:id])
    @exercise_image.destroy

    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

How to fix this controller to use `authorize_resource` method ? I need to authorize Exercise::Image instances.

Edit:
I'd like to use `authorize_resource` because `load_and_authorize` is too intrusive for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of your controller. See the documentation here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: Well I'd like to use only `authorize_resource`; `load_and_authorize_resource` is too intrusive for me

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason for that? Specially with the ability to set `skip_load_resource` for whatever actions you don't want load to happen on?